# Removed canonical partners repository

Tags: canonical

I have removed the canonical partners repository from other software in software & updates, so what can i do to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```